# c++ how can I write single-process named_mutex?

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex

I need a class which will allow me to lock/unlock specific names (or simply indexes), and I don't want it to be multi-processing, so I can run multiple instances of my application. Also I want to avoid use of system-specific APIs, just std or boost. (For simplicity sake, we can say: max number of names/indexes used at the same time is 100)

Unfortunately I has no usage example for you, I just interested is it possible to make.

I tried to find anything like that, but all I found is `boost::interprocess::named_mutex` and some WinApi methods, like `CreateMutexW`.

I also tried to write my own code (below), but it definitely not perfect and has at least one potential bug.

So, does anyone has any suggestion, code ideas, or already existing classes?

Thanks in advance

```cpp
class IndexMutex
{
public:
    void Lock(uint32_t id);
    void Unlock(uint32_t id);

private:
    struct IndexLock
    {
        static constexpr uint32_t unlocked = ~0u;
        void Lock(uint32_t id) {
            index_ = id;
            mutex_.lock();
        }
        void Unlock() {
            mutex_.unlock();
            index_ = unlocked;
        }
        bool IsLocked() const {
            return index_ != unlocked;
        }

        std::atomic<uint32_t> index_ = unlocked;
        std::mutex mutex_{};
    };

    std::array<IndexLock, 100> mutexes_{};
    std::mutex masterMutex_{};
};

void IndexMutex::Lock(uint32_t id)
{
    if (id == IndexLock::unlocked) {
        return;
    }

    const std::lock_guard<std::mutex> __guard{ masterMutex_ };

    uint32_t possibleId = IndexLock::unlocked;

    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < mutexes_.size(); ++i) {
        if (mutexes_[i].index_ == id) {
            masterMutex_.unlock();

            // POTENTIAL BUG: TIME GAP

            mutexes_[i].Lock(id);

            return;
        }
        // Searching for unlocked mutex in the same time.
        if (possibleId == IndexLock::unlocked && !mutexes_[i].IsLocked()) {
            possibleId = i;
        }
    }

    if (possibleId == IndexLock::unlocked) {
        throw std::runtime_error{ "No locks were found." };
    }

    // We are sure here, that mutex can't be locked
    // because we were protected by the muster mutex all that time.
    mutexes_[possibleId].Lock(id);
}

void IndexMutex::Unlock(uint32_t id)
{
    if (id == IndexLock::unlocked) {
        return;
    }

    const std::lock_guard<std::mutex> __guard{ masterMutex_ };

    for (auto& lock : mutexes_) {
        if (lock.index_ == id) {
            lock.Unlock();
            return;
        }
    }

    throw std::runtime_error{ "No mutexes there found by specified index." };
}
```

Comment: It isn't quite clear why you need all this machinery. Why won't a plain std::array of mutexes work for you?

Comment: What do you mean by that? If you suggesting to use separate mutex for each possible index, it will be great memory overhead (we can have up to 4294967294 different indexes, and much more names). 
If you mean to just remove `musterMutex_` from my code for simplicity (to just have array with mutexes which can accept indexes), when we will run into problem when two thread can lock same index..

Comment: Ok it looks like you want something like a (thread-safe) `map<int, mutex>`.

Comment: in some way yes, but how to make map<int,mutex> thread-safe without deadlocking on mutex part..

Comment: Why do you expect a deadlock? There shouldn't be any. Just have a master mutex protecting the map.

Comment: Why don't you just swap around the two lines next to the `// POTENTIAL BUG: TIME GAP` and then there will be an overlap instead of a gap?

Comment: Ok, if for example we have thread searching for index 1. It finds mutex with this index (it will mean this mutex is locked, because unlocked mutexes has `IndexLock::unlocked` as their index) and it will try to lock on it without unlocking master mutex. This thread will wait untill his mutex is unlocked, but because of that none other thread will have access to the entire map, because as you remember master mutex is still locked..

Comment: What is the purpose of the `IsLocked()` method? In a multi-threaded environment,  you can not rely on the result returned by `IsLocked()` to tell you whether or not the mutex is locked. It can only tell whether or not the mutex _was_ locked at some arbitrary instant in the recent past. By the time `IsLocked()` returns a result to the caller though, some other thread already could have changed the status of the lock.

Comment: Totally agree. As I said this code isn't perfect nor workable. It is just my implementation try used as example for some corner cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a *reference counted* mutex map, protected by a master mutex. An implementation in terms of

```
std::map<int, std::pair<int, std::mutex>>
```

would do the job.

The lock operation works like this (untested pseudocode):

```
master.lock()
std::pair<int, std::mutex>& m = mymap[index]; //inserts a new one if needed       
m.first++;
master.unlock();
m.second.lock();
```

The unlock operation:

```
master.lock();
std::pair<int, std::mutex>& m = mymap[index];
m.second.unlock();
m.first--;
if (m.first==0) mymap.remove(index);
master.unlock();
```

No deadlocks! It is possible to first unlock the master and then lock the found mutex. Even if another thread intervenes and unlocks the mutex, the reference count won't drop to zero and the mutex will not be removed.

Comment: Thanks a lot) I think this is the solution I looked for)

Comment: The only thing I would suggest is to use `map::find` in the unlock operation instead of `operator[]`, so we sure index is actually in the map. If by any chance we get incorrect index, the count of that mutex after unlocking will became -1.

Comment: This is just a rough outline, adjust as needed.